# Are the pronouns "Thee" and "Thy" considered archaisms in 19th Century poetry?

Tags: thou-thee-thy

Are the pronouns "Thee" and "Thy" considered archaisms in Romantic poetry? I have La Belle Dame sans Merci by Keats in mind.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Thee%2Cthou%2Cthy&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1550&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CThee%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthee%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthou%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthou%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThou%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthy%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThy%3B%2Cc0 is a ngram for thee/thy/thou.

Comment: Considered by who, in what context? Opinion-based.

Comment: Yes, almost certainly, but I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really more literary than it about English usage.

Comment: @Rob_Ster I think this question is properly addressed here--it addresses a matter of linguistic usage within a literary text rather than literary intepretation.

Answer (score 2):

As MikeJRamsey56 says, the second-person singular forms had largely fallen out of ordinary use a hundred and fifty years before Keats wrote. However, in some literary genres—notably religious discourse and lyric poetry—they remained current until the end of the Victorian era.

In the case of 'La Belle Dame Sans Merci' the archaic singulars are in fact particularly decorous, since Keats is consciously emulating the style of the late-medieval ballad. There weren't a whole lot of knights-errant wandering the Victorian landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes.

> By the 1600s, the singular forms had come to represent familiarity and
>   lack of status, and fell from use except in the case of a few
>   dialects, notably in the north of England. People in Lancashire north
>   of the Rossendale Forest and Yorkshire formerly were noted for use of
>   the singular second person pronouns tha (nom.) and thee (acc.). For
>   religious reasons (Christian equality of persons, but also justified
>   as grammatically correct), the Quakers also retained the familiar
>   forms.  [Thee](https://www.etymonline.com/word/thee)

Comment: Interesting, but not wholly responsive to OP's question, which specifically focuses on Romantic verse in general and Keats in particular. :-(

Comment: True. I was going more on out of date during the 17th century vs. the 19th-century context of the question. By the 19th century "thee" and "thou" were out of date in most usages.  "Poetic license" gives the writer "freedom from the conventional rules of language when speaking or writing in order to create an effect."  So any use of language in poetry can be appropriate.